# echoing text file from smallest string to largest

Tags: php

I have a text file with a new word on every line. Im trying to read it so it echoes the smallest string to largest. Heres my script but its not working!

```
<?php
$file = fopen("domains.txt", "r");
$members = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
$members[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);
arsort($members);
var_dump($members);
?>
```

Comment: can we have a sample of the file contents and the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function sortByLength($a,$b){
    return strlen($b)-strlen($a);
}

usort($members,'sortByLength');

print_r($members);
```